# Navigation Drawer, support design. Text color of highlighted item

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-support-design

I'm building a navigation drawer using the android's support design lib. I would like to customize the colors of the text showed in that navigation drawer, so I've used a style to do that.

My Navigation Drawer.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:theme="@style/NavigationViewTheme"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation" />
```

My style

```
    <style name="NavigationViewTheme" parent="AppTheme">
                <item name="textAppearanceListItem">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2</item>
    <!--CHANGE TEXT COLOR -->            
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <!-- CHANGE ICON COLOR -->            
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
        </style>
```

What I want to change now, is the color of the highlighted text and icon. I've tried with so many items but nothing changes.

I've tried with all of these

```
<item name="textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text_dark</item>
        <item name="textColorSecondary">@color/secondary_text_dark</item>
        <item name="textColorTertiary">@color/tertiary_text_dark</item>
        <item name="textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/primary_text_light</item>
        <item name="textColorSecondaryInverse">@color/secondary_text_light</item>
        <item name="textColorTertiaryInverse">@color/tertiary_text_light</item>
        <item name="textColorPrimaryActivated">@color/primary_text_dark</item>
        <item name="textColorSecondaryActivated">@color/secondary_text_dark</item>
        <item name="textColorPrimaryDisableOnly">@color/primary_text_dark_disable_only</item>
        <item name="textColorPrimaryInverseDisableOnly">@color/primary_text_light_disable_only</item>
        <item name="textColorPrimaryNoDisable">@color/primary_text_dark_nodisable</item>
        <item name="textColorSecondaryNoDisable">@color/secondary_text_dark_nodisable</item>
        <item name="textColorPrimaryInverseNoDisable">@color/primary_text_light_nodisable</item>
        <item name="textColorSecondaryInverseNoDisable">@color/secondary_text_light_nodisable</item>
        <item name="textColorHint">@color/hint_foreground_dark</item>
        <item name="textColorHintInverse">@color/hint_foreground_light</item>
        <item name="textColorSearchUrl">@color/search_url_text</item>
        <item name="textColorHighlight">@color/highlighted_text_dark</item>
        <item name="textColorHighlightInverse">@color/highlighted_text_light</item>
        <item name="textColorLink">@color/link_text_dark</item>
        <item name="textColorLinkInverse">@color/link_text_light</item>
        <item name="textColorAlertDialogListItem">@color/primary_text_light_disable_only</item>
```

Comment: How about changing the text color of the text view in the items of the drawer?

Comment: I'm using the support design lib @Joshua. I've created my items using this pattern http://antonioleiva.com/navigation-view/ . I think that I'cant change the color in the way that you've said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. I only need to add

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
```

to my navigation drawer style.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, set `app:itemTextColor="@color/navigation_view_color"` to your `NavigationView`.

navigation_view_color:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:color="@color/highlighted_color" />
    <item android:color="@color/black" />
</selector>
```